# Data from PDO query returning nothing - Suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

unsure why this is not working, suddenly stopped working today randomly.
$row is returning nothing for some reason and when I try to format the date I get an error as its not valid.

Any help appreciated.

```
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM notifications");
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt -> fetchAll();

    foreach( $result as $row ) {
        $recipient = $row['recipient'];
        $day = $row['day'];
        $month = $row['month'];
        $year = $row['year'];
        $hour = $row['hour'];
        $minute = $row['minute'];


//Now we need to convert the times for this row into meaningful data
        $date = $day . "." . $month . "." . $year . " " . $hour . ":" . $minute . ":45";
        echo "<br/><br/>";

        echo "Date: " . $date;
        $dateObject = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i:s', $date);
        $formattedDate = $dateObject->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        //Get current time
        $currentDate = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('Australia/Perth'));
        $currentDate = $currentDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        //Now we have current date and time, as well as date and time from table of db.
        //Lets compare the times.

        if ($formattedDate < $currentDate) {
            //License expired
            sendPushNotifcation($recipient);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM notifications WHERE `recipient` ='".$recipient."'");
            $stmt->execute();
        }


    }
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the variables, are you missing some `echo` statements?

Comment: I just didn't include the full script I am doing something ill update question now

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with how you're doing the query.

Comment: Thats my problem, it was working and now it has just stopped working.

Comment: Why do you store all the parts of the time separately, instead of in a `DATETIME` column?

Comment: The output from the script is this (from echo in script) : Date: .. ::45

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` show?

Comment: Im more worried about why I cant access the data right now. However it is due to the way an app communicates with the server

Comment: array(12) { ["recipient"]=> string(0) "" [0]=> string(0) "" ["day"]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" ["month"]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" ["year"]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" ["hour"]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" ["minute"]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" }

There is definately data in the rows in the DB, so I dont understand why its all empty strings in var_dump

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would return that other than an empty row in the table.

Comment: Is it printing that for every row?

Comment: https://imgur.com/9kzQyTq Screenshot of db table

Comment: What if you use `while ($row = $stmt->fetch())` instead of using `$result = $stmt->fetchAll()`?

Comment: Same result when I do that

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code.  Are you sure you're connecting to the right DB server? Other than that, it seems like either your DB or PDO is broken.

Comment: I am, because I executed a test insert query and it ran just fine. Maybe ill try restart mysql

Comment: maybe what you need to try is checking the connection between dbms mysql and your web app, I only picture one possible problem... it is your hosting problem in mysql